# Core Data v SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, xcode4

I have to write an app which shares data with an existing app. If I use SQLite I assume I can open the same table that is used by my original app and update the data, so both apps can share the data. Does Core Data allow the same as I would prefer to use Core Data?

Comment: Core Data uses SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data can use a few different store types (binary, XML or SQLite). But that isn't important really. So long as both apps have the same data model with which to reference the stored data then the apps can 'share' the data store file (no matter which format it is stored in).